About the dual of a vector-valued weak-* Lebesgue space
Here, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open, bounded set (as nice as you want). It is well known that $L^1(\Omega)^* = L^\infty(\Omega)$. Moreover, it is also true that if we endow $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with the weak-* topology (let us denote this space $L^\infty_*(\Omega)$), we also have that $$L^\infty_*(\Omega)^* = L^1(\Omega)$$ (see for example here). In this way, these two spaces (one with the strong topology, and one with the weak-* topology) are mutually dual to each other - I think some authors such as Rockaferral refer in general to this situation as being "paired spaces", but I'm not completely sure of that.
Similarly, but more generally, if $X$ is a Banach space, it is also true that $L^1(\Omega;X)^*=L^\infty_*(\Omega;X^*)$, where $L^1(\Omega;X)$ is the (normed) space of Bochner integrable functions, and $L^\infty_*(\Omega;X^*)$ is the (normed) space of weakly-* measurable functions $g:\Omega\to X^*$ such that there exists a $c>0$ such that $|\langle g(\omega),x \rangle| \le c\|x\|_X$ for a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$ and all $x\in X$ (the norm here is given by the smallest $c$). As a reference, I have the Dinculeanu-Foias theorem (Theorem 2.2.12) of Gasinski-Papageorgiou
My question is: is it also true that (as in the standard case)
$$ L^\infty_*(\Omega;X^*)^* = L^1(\Omega;X) $$
?
Any hint would be very much appreciated!

I think the star notation is a bit confusing. You should distinguish $L^\infty_* (\Omega):= (L^\infty(\Omega),w^*)$ which is $L^\infty$ with the weak-star topology and $L_*^\infty(\Omega,X^*)$ which is something completely different. I think the commonly used notation for the latter is either $L^\infty(\Omega, X^*_{w^*})$ or $L^\infty_w(\Omega,X^*)$.
If you are asking whether
$$L^\infty(\Omega,X^*_{w^*})^*= L^1(\Omega,X)$$
then this is not true as one can see by the one dimensional example of  $X=\mathbb R$  since $L^\infty(\Omega,\mathbb R^*_{w^*})= L^\infty(\Omega) $ and $L^\infty(\Omega)^* \neq L^1(\Omega)$.

Since $L^1(\Omega,X)^* = L^\infty(\Omega,X^*_{w^*}) $ you always have that $$ (L_*^\infty(\Omega,X^*_{w^*}))^*=L^1(\Omega,X).$$
Now, when  $X^*$ has the RNP then $L^\infty(\Omega,X^*_{w^*})=L^\infty(\Omega,X^*) = L^1(\Omega,X)^*$ and so
$$ L_*^\infty(\Omega,X^*)^* = L_*^\infty(\Omega,X^*_{w^*})^*=L^1(\Omega,X) .$$
It could be the case that the last equality is true iff $X^*$ has RNP but I am not sure at the moment.

Thank you very much for your nice answer! I feel like I am missing something: what is the difference between $L^\infty(\Omega;X^)$ and $L^\infty(\Omega;X^_{w^*})$ in your notation?

@rod  The former is the classic Bochner space of all strongly measurable  $f \colon \Omega \to X^$ that are essentially bounded (i.e. $\inf { M>0 \colon |f(\omega)|_{X^} \le M \text { a.a. } \omega }<\infty$), whereas the latter is the space of all weak-star measurable $f \colon \Omega \to X^*$ such that $\langle f(\omega), x \rangle \le c |x|$ a.a $\omega$. You can find more details in Chapter 4.2 of the book Applied Nonlinear Functional Analysis
An Introduction

Ok, thanks again. It looks to me that the norms of these two spaces coincide, i.e.  if $f\in L^\infty(\Omega;X^)\subseteq L^\infty(\Omega;X^{w^*})$, then $|f|{L^\infty(\Omega;X^)}=|f|_{L^\infty(\Omega;X^{w*})}$. If that is the case,  it should be $L^\infty(\Omega;X^)={f\in L^\infty(\Omega;X^{w^*}):f\text{ is strongly measurable}}$. Does that make sense?

You have to be careful as in general the null set depends on $x \in X$. In the case $X$ is separable then the null set in the definition of $f \in L^\infty(\Omega,X^_{w^})$ does not depend on $x$ and so you have that the two norms are in fact the same and what you wrote is correct. Example 4.2.31 in the book gives a counterexample in the non separable case.

Ok, I read the example. For some reason, it's a picture that I struggle to keep in mind, so maybe my next comment is completely on a wrong track.  Let us say that I have a specific $X$ such that if $f(\omega)\in X^*$, then $\langle f(\omega), \nu \rangle =0\ \forall \nu\in X$ implies that $f(\omega)=0$. Do I possibly gain something (such as for example the equality between those two norms in my previous comment)?

You mean if $f$ is such that $\langle f(\omega), x \rangle =0$ for every $x \in X$ a.e. (again, a.e. depends on $x$) implies that $f =0$ a.e. (so a.e. does not actually depend on $x$) then maybe the two norms are the same? I am not sure I can think of something right now

The notation "$f(\omega)$" was redundant as there is no need for a function $f$ - it was just to be consistent with your notation. I meant even something stronger: $X$ is such that for any $x^\in X^$, $\langle x^*,\nu\rangle=0\ \forall \nu\in X$ implies that  $x=0$.
